# Recursive approach taking too long to compute the result

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a set of `offers` and I have a `cart of Items`. The set of offers is such that all the offers in that set are conflicting offers, which means that more than one offer can be applied on an item in the cart.

Example:

```
These are my offers:
offerId  Offer Description
1        vim+cabbage will give discount of 500
2        cabbage has rs 50 discount
3        vim has Rs. 30 discount

This is my cart:

Item      : quantity
cabbage   : 10
vim       : 5
```

Now I want to find the best offer I can apply to the cart. In above case best offer will be I apply offer 1 on 5 quantities each of vim and cabbage which will give me a total discount of 5*500 and on remaining 5 quantities of cabbage I apply offer 2 which will give me discount of 5*50.

so my total discount is : 5*500 + 5*50 = 2750.

to note that the other option would have been to apply offer 2 on 10 quantities of cabbage and offer 3 on 5 quantities of vim. which would have given me a discount of : 10*50 + 5*30 = 650 which is less than the first case. But this is wrong as the best offers will be the above one.

Now this is only one of the example. I can have many overlapping offers nd many items in cart on which offers are getting overlapped.

I tried a recursive approach to solve this problem. Pseudocode is here:

```
 func recursive(offers, cartItems){
       if(offers[0] is applicable on cartItems){
       lDiscount = recursive(offers-offer[0], cartItems -variantsOnWhichOfferApplied) + discount 

        rDiscount = recursive(offers - offers[0],cartItems)
        if (lDiscount > rDiscount){
             return lDiscount
         } else{
             return rDiscount
        }  

 }else{
         recursive(offers-offer[0],cartItems)
    }
        }
```

offers is an array of offers :

In this case: offer 1 can be applied 5 times on cart, offer 2 can be applied 10 times and offer 3 can be applied 5 times. So in `offers` array I have entries like this:

```
offers = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
```

I am getting the right answer but recursion is taking too long to solve this.

Can anyone tell me how to convert it into dp or if there is any other way I can decrease the time complexity of this method.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like Linear Program (aka linear optimization problem) for me. Depending on what Your situation is, the most easy solution could be to use some free LP-solver.

The LP for the sample problem would be (in lp-format)

    max: 500 o1 + 50 o2 + 30 o3 ;

    o1 + o3 <= 5;

    o1 + o2 <= 10;

Comment: @Tymur I don't understand o1 + o3 <= 5; o1 + o2 <= 10

Comment: o1, o2, o3 are the variables corresponding to the offers.
The 5 units of "vim" can be used with o1 or o3, thus we can at most have 5 units of o1 and o3 together: `o1 + o3 <= 5;`
10 units of "cabbage" result in `o1 + o2 <= 10;`

Comment: If you can sort your offers by quality, then you can probably apply them greedily. In your example they are already sorted correctly. So you would try to apply 1 as many times as possible, then 2 and finally 3. As you can see in your example it would give the correct solution. It's not perfect, but fast.

Comment: What are the restriction on offers? Can they be something like discount of 50 when you buy 3 or more?

Comment: @maraca I had actually tried that approach , but yeah there are cases in which it is not giving me correct solution.

Comment: @suyog I have to have offers such as buy 3 or more.. but currently I am writing algorithm for above kind of offers only.